# Deleting rows till first empty row

Tags: vba, excel

This is a sample format of my spreadsheet. I tried to write code for deleting rows from row(2) to first blank cell, but there is a problem when there is less data (means upto row 20-30). This is not working properly & deleting all rows. But it is working when data is in more than 30 rows.

column A
   row1 company name    remove
   row2 address line    remove
   row3 address line    remove
   row4 address line    remove
   row5 address line    remove
   row6 address line    remove
   row7 Customer Name   KEEP THIS
   row8 address line    remove
   row9 address line    remove
   row10 address line   remove
   row11 address line   remove
   row12 address line   remove
   row13 address line   remove
   row14 address line   remove
   row15 BLANK ROW      remove
   row16 DATE RANGE (like 01-jan-16 to 31-jan-16     => KEEP THIS
   row17 bLANK ROW      remove
   row18 ROW HEADINGS   KEEP THIS
   row19 DATA   DATA DONT CHANGE ALL DATA
   row20 DATA   DATA 
   row21 DATA   DATA 
   row22 DATA   DATA
   row23 DATA   DATA

I tried to do this with the code below:

```
Sub EmptyRowFind()
    Dim sourceCol As Integer, rowCount As Integer, currentRow As Integer
    Dim currentRowValue As String

    sourceCol = 1
    rowCount = Cells(20, sourceCol).Row
    For currentRow = 1 To rowCount
        currentRowValue = Cells(currentRow, sourceCol).Value
        If IsEmpty(currentRowValue) Or currentRowValue = "" Then
            For i = i To currentRow - 2
                Rows(1).Select
                Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
            Next
        End If

End Sub
```

Comment: i think problem is in For i = i To currentRow - 2

Comment: Oh, sorry I am not shouting, it was my mistake to write in CAPS I extremely

Comment: sorry for this, I did not care while writing about CAPS lock.

Comment: this is a sample format of my spreadsheet i tried to write a code for deleting row but there is problem when there is less data (means upto row 20-30) this is not working properly & deleting all rows. but it is working when data is in more than 30 rows. i couldn't find the error pls go through the code i tried & help to correct it.

Comment: @Nafis, now that you recognized you shouldn't have used caps lock in your question, can you please edit it accordingly?

Comment: I need to delete some rows in my excel sheet, so I wrote above code to do the same. Actually I need to do is find first blank row & delete all above rows from row(2) to first blank row. My code is working properly when the sheet has data in more than 25-35 rows. but when there is less data (approx less than 25 rows) this macro is deleting all data (even my working data). Pls help to find my mistake

Comment: all has to be done in column A

Comment: @Nafis: Please EDIT YOUR ORIGINAL QUESTION!!!1 Remove the caps locked text and while you're at it, put the aditional info from the comments there as well. And please have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Sir, sorry to annoy all of you as I am new here so I am committing such silly mistakes. Now I have edited my question.

Comment: @Nafis: Being new is not the problem, ignoring what we tell you is. Thanks for removing the caps lock text, but I still couldn't understand the question so I edited it myself. Please take a look at it and fix the obvious error of the missing `Next`. Also put an `Option Explicit` in the first line of your module, that will enforce the declaration of all variables. If the problem still persists please update your question with the current code and an exact description of what errors you get.

Comment: @Nafis: You tell us when you're done editing? You haven't done anything I asked for in my last comment yet, furthermore you destroyed the format of your question, making it worse that it was before. Fix all of that and then come back to us, will you?

Comment: can you post simple image of your spreadsheets?

Answer (score 0):

Thank a lot to all of you specially to Mr. Leviathan for giving me so quick response. As I have solve the problem by myself yeh... find my new edited code

```
Sub EmptyRowFind()
Dim sourceCol As Integer, rowCount As Integer, currentRow As Integer
Dim currentRowValue As String

sourceCol = 1
rowCount = Cells(20, sourceCol).Row
For currentRow = 1 To rowCount
    currentRowValue = Cells(currentRow, sourceCol).Value
    If IsEmpty(currentRowValue) Or currentRowValue = "" Then
        For i = i To currentRow - 2
            Rows(1).Select
            Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
        Next
    End If
If IsEmpty(currentRowValue) Or currentRowValue = "" Then'==>Now added 
Exit For
End If
Next
End Sub
```

Exlanation :- When old code was run isempty loop deleted rows when it found empty row but again it returned to first for loop (currentrow=1 to rowcount)
& again it runs the loop with deleting rows untill second empty row. this process was going on for 20 times(as rowcount=20).